# Number guessing game php

Tags: php

I am making a PHP number guessing game in order to learn SESSIONS and POST / GET
The problem I am having is that the Number too low and number too high are not working I am using xampp on a local host.

form.php

```
<form class="" action="index.php" method="post">
    <p>Guesses:<input type="number" name="guess" required></p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Guess">
</form>
```

index.php

```
<center>
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["number"])) {
  $_SESSION["number"] = mt_rand(1,10);
  $_SESSION["counter"] = 0;
}
if (isset($_POST["guess"])) {
  if ($_POST['guess']== $_SESSION['number']) {
    echo "<br><br><br><br>Correct<br>"."Your number was ". 
$_SESSION["number"]."<br>"."<a href='reset.php'>Play Again </a>";
    session_destroy();
  }else {
    $_SESSION["counter"] = $_SESSION["counter"] + 1;
    include("form.php");
    echo"Incorrect try again<br>";
    echo $_SESSION["counter"]. " Guesses";

    if ($_POST["guess"] > $_SESSION["number"]) { //greater than
    $_POST["guess"]." is too big Try a smaller number.";

    } else if ($_POST["guess"] < $_SESSION["number"]) { //less than
    $_POST["guess"]." is too small Try a larger number.";
    }
    echo "<br><a href='reset.php'>RESET </a>";
  }
 }else {
  include("form.php");
 }
?>
</center>
```

Comment: `$_POST["guess"]." is too big Try a smaller number.";` You don't echo. Same for the `else if`

Comment: session_start() must be placed before all sends to the browser (<center>)

Comment: Thanks worked perfect